# Git commands for the following use cases (revert / reset, etc)

Tags: git

1) I have not committed nor pushed but i have made some wrong changes and i want to roll back.

2) I have committed but not pushed and i made some wrong changes. Now i want to roll back.

3) I have committed and pushed and i made some wrong changes. Now i want to roll back.

4) I was working in the files a.java and b.java, and i pulled the code, but as soon as i pull it there are conflicts, what is the best way to resolve lots of conflicts.

5) I was working in the files a.java and b.java, and i pulled the code, but as soon as i pull it there are conflicts, I need changes of file b.java and i dont want to use my version of file a.java. How to solve it?

6) I have committed my code and i go home , next day i come back and push the code but i can not push because there are conflicts since i did not work with the updated file ( i forgot to pull from server).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might get a better response if you edit your question so it reads less like a list of demands and more like a request for help.

Comment: I would recommend perusing https://git-scm.com/doc

Comment: Agreed - Stack Overflow is a good place to get help with a specific technical problem. If you want handy reference on git for these hypothetical problems, there's loads of guides and reference material out there already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation) or the [Git Reference Page](https://git-scm.com/docs). These are all pretty standard use cases.

1), 2) and 3) are standard use cases.

4) Use a file comparison tool like Kdiff3 to merge the two files together. There is a [Massive amount of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).

5) Revert a.java then merge b.java as per 4).

6) Cancel your push, pull from the server, resolve as per 4), and then push the merged files.